# Jtable is not printing (blank document is printed)

Tags: java, jtable

```
Jtable table=somevalues;    table.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH,null,null,true,null,true,null);
```

The print dialog box is opening but when I print the table is not printed only blank document is printed. Could someone tell me where I am going wrong?
I have **edited ** and the code with values is

```
String data[][]=new String[1][9];
                    String head[]=new String[9];

                    head[0]="Date";
                    head[1]="Q1 Rate per piece";
                    head[2]="Q1 Total pieces";
                    head[3]="Q2 Rate per piece";
                    head[4]="Q2 Total pieces";
                    head[5]="Q3 Rate per piece";
                    head[6]="Q3 Total pieces";
                    head[7]="Total pieces";
                    head[8]="Total Amount";

                        data[0][0]="a";
                        data[0][1]="b";
                        data[0][2]="c";
                        data[0][3]="d";
                        data[0][4]="e";
                        data[0][5]="f";
                        data[0][6]="g";
                        data[0][7]="h";
                        data[0][8]="i";
                     JTable table=new JTable(data,head);
                boolean complete=table.print();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

The easiest way to print your table is to call the print method without parameters. See the code example below.

```
try {
    boolean complete = table.print();
    if (complete) {
        /* show a success message  */
        ...
    } else {
        /*show a message indicating that printing was cancelled */
        ...
    }
} catch (PrinterException pe) {
    /* Printing failed, report to the user */
    ...
}
```

When you call the print method with no parameters, a print dialog is displayed, and then your table is printed interactively in the FIT_WIDTH mode without a header or a footer. The code example below shows the print method signature with the complete set of arguments.

```
boolean complete = table.print(JTable.PrintMode printMode,
                               MessageFormat headerFormat,
                               MessageFormat footerFormat, 
                               boolean showPrintDialog,
                               PrintRequestAttributeSet attr,
                               boolean interactive,
                               PrintService service);
```

When you call the print method with all arguments, you explicitly choose printing features such as a printing mode, a header and a footer text, printing attributes, a destination print service, and also whether to show a print dialog or not, and whether to print interactively or non-interactively. To decide which parameters suit your needs best, see the description of available features below.

The JTable printing API provides the following features:

Printing Interactively or Non-interactively
Displaying a Print Dialog
Adding a Header or a Footer (or Both) to a Printing Layout
Selecting a Printing Mode
Automatic Layout and Pagination

**Solution 2**

The following is an example to print a jtable

```
public JTable()
JTable table = new JTable();

public JTable(int rows, int columns)
JTable table = new JTable(2, 3);

public JTable(Object rowData[][], Object columnNames[])
Object rowData[][] = { { "Row1-Column1", "Row1-Column2", "Row1-Column3"},
                       { "Row2-Column1", "Row2-Column2", "Row2-Column3"} };
Object columnNames[] = { "Column One", "Column Two", "Column Three"};
JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);

public JTable(TableModel model)
TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames);
JTable table = new JTable(model);

public JTable(TableModel model, TableColumnModel columnModel)
TableColumnModel columnModel = new DefaultTableColumnModel();
TableColumn firstColumn = new TableColumn(1);
firstColumn.setHeaderValue(headers[1]);columnModel.addColumn(firstColumn);
TableColumn secondColumn = new TableColumn(0);
secondColumn.setHeaderValue(headers[0]);
columnModel.addColumn(secondColumn);
JTable table = new JTable(model, columnModel);

public JTable(TableModel model, TableColumnModel columnModel, ListSelectionModel selectionModel)
ListSelectionModel selectionModel = new DefaultListSelectionModel();
selectionModel.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
JTable table = new JTable(model, columnModel, selectionModel);
```

Comment: I am sorry. I am just a beginner. I don't see any method to print the values of table. I have initialized the values of the table. To reduce the posting code length I just mentioned it as somevalues

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Now I tried it but only the outline of the header is printing but not printing the values inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
  public class TablePrint extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        /**
         * Creates new form TablePrint
         */
        public TablePrint() {
            initComponents();
        }

      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
        private void initComponents() {

            jButtonPrint = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
            jTableData = new javax.swing.JTable();

            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            jButtonPrint.setText("Print");
            jButtonPrint.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jButtonPrintActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            jTableData.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
                new Object [][] {
                    {null, null},
                    {null, null},
                    {null, null},
                    {null, null}
                },
                new String [] {
                    "Name", "Age"
                }
            ));
            jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTableData);

            javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(39, 39, 39)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jButtonPrint)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addContainerGap(50, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 105, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jButtonPrint)
                    .addGap(0, 34, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );

            pack();
        }// </editor-fold>                        

        private void jButtonPrintActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
           try{
                jTableData.print();
            }catch(Exception ee){}
        }                                            

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String args[]) {

            /* Create and display the form */
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new TablePrint().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton jButtonPrint;
        private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
        private javax.swing.JTable jTableData;
        // End of variables declaration                   
    }
```